# What does 'height: 0;' mean in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am working with some old code of css. At many places they have declared height as ***height: 0;***. what this **0** means and in which unit it is?

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: What does 0 means to you?

Comment: Zero cars and zero badgers is a world of difference ;)

Comment: We don't need no stinking badgers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in **css** **height**  means the physical height of an element.

it is same as `height:0px` or `height:0%`.

suppose the following html elements one is having a property `height:0;` and another is having a property `height:100px` let's see what happen

```css
#me {
  height: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}
#me2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="me" style="">this is an element</div>
<br/>
<div id="me2" style="">this is an element</div>
```

Comment: because i didnot have any other appropriate words in my mind. i meant it as element's height

Answer (score 6):

"0" doesn't need an unit as `height:0;` is the same as `height: 0px;` or `height: 0%;`

```
height:0;
```

The result really depends on what element is targeted:
EX:

```
#parentdiv{height:0;}
```

This just maked the parent div is 0px in height, but that doesn't mean that the child div will not show up, that will only happen if overflow:hidden; would be used also.
So it really depends on what element it was appended to.

Answer (score 2):

If image

0% = 100% :-D

```css
img {height: 0%}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"></img>
```

But 0% is not 0 or 0px

```css
img {height: 0}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"></img>
```

```css
img {height: 0px}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"></img>
```